# Problems with fail and backtrack

Tags: prolog

I am working on a program that tests if a person can become a citizen or not. When a person in the database is passed in, it should return all of the reasons they do or do not qualify. My issue is that to show all the reasons, I use fail to backtrack and find other reasons, this makes the return false when it should be true.

```
born(frank,usa,1944). 
child(frank,mary,jack).
child(mary,sean,ruth).
born(fiona,usa,1920).
child(fiona,sean,ruth).

citizen(X):- born(X,'irl',_).
natcitizen(X):-naturalized(X,_). 
marriedirl(X):-married(X,Y,_),born(Y,'irl',_).
adoptedirl(X):-adopted(X,P1,P2),born(P1,'irl',_),born(P2,'irl',_).
irlparent(X):-child(X,P1,P2),(born(P1,'irl',_);born(P2,'irl',_)).
irlgrandparent(X):- child(X,P1,P2),(child(P1,G1,G2),(born(G1,'irl',_);born(G2,'irl',_));child(P2,G3,G4),(born(G3,'irl',_);born(G4,'irl',_))).
permres5(X):-(permres(X,Start,End),born(X,_,B),A is B, 2015-A@>=18,End==2015,N is End-Start,(N@>=5)).


qualify(X):- \+(citizen(X) ->write(X) ->write_ln( ' is already an irish born citizen')), \+ (natcitizen(X)  ->write(X) ->write( ' is already a naturalized Irish citizen')),
(marriedirl(X)->write(X) ->write_ln(' qualifies: he/she is married to an Irish citizen'));
(adoptedirl(X))->write(X) ->write_ln(' qualifies: he/she was adopted by Irish-born parents');
(irlparent(X)->write(X) ->write_ln(' qualifies: he/she has an Irish parent')),fail;
(irlgrandparent(X) ->write(X) ->write_ln(' qualifies: he/she has an Irish grandparent')),fail;
(permres5(X) ->write(X) ->write_ln(' qualifies: he/she is an Irish permanent resident and has been for at least 5 years')),fail.
```

So when fiona is called:
fiona qualifies: he/she has an Irish parent
false.
is returned instead of true.

for frank its:
frank qualifies: he/she has an Irish parent
frank qualifies: he/she has an Irish grandparent
false.

again it should say true, I am unsure how to change the truth value without changing fail, and breaking the backtracking.

pastebin of entire code: http://pastebin.com/tp7Mi5s6

Comment: maybe just write_ln should be writeln

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using to force enumeration of all solutions is called a "failure driven loop".

All-solution predicates like `setof/3` may be better suited to what you need.

First, I'd replace `qualify/1` with `person_qualified_reason/3`:

```
person_qualified_reason(P,Decision,Reason) :-
   citizen(P),
   !,
   Decision = no,
   Reason   = 'already an irish born citizen'.
person_qualified_reason(P,Decision,Reason) :-
   natcitizen(P),
   !,
   Decision = no,
   Reason   = 'already a naturalized Irish citizen'.
person_qualified_reason(P,yes,'married to an Irish citizen') :-
   marriedirl(P).
person_qualified_reason(P,yes,'adopted by Irish-born parents') :-
   adoptedirl(P).
person_qualified_reason(P,yes,'has an Irish parent') :-
   irlparent(P).
person_qualified_reason(P,yes,'has an Irish grandparent') :-
   irlgrandparent(P).
person_qualified_reason(P,yes,'has been Irish permanent resident for 5+ years') :-
   permres5(P).
```

Sample query:

```
?- person_qualified_reason(frank,D,Reason).
D = yes, Reason = 'has an Irish parent' ;
D = yes, Reason = 'has an Irish parent' ;            % redundant answer
D = yes, Reason = 'has an Irish grandparent' ;
D = yes, Reason = 'has an Irish grandparent' ;       % redundant answer
false.
```

To collect all reasons, we can use the builtin `setof/3`:

```
?- setof(Decision-Reason,person_qualified_reason(frank,Decision,Reason),All).
All = [yes-'has an Irish grandparent', yes-'has an Irish parent'].
```

`knownPerson/1` holds true for all persons known in the database:

```
knownPerson(X) :- adopted(X,_,_).
knownPerson(X) :- adopted(_,X,_).
knownPerson(X) :- adopted(_,_,X).
knownPerson(X) :- naturalized(X,_).
knownPerson(X) :- permres(X,_,_).
knownPerson(X) :- child(X,_,_).
knownPerson(X) :- child(_,X,_).
knownPerson(X) :- child(_,_,X).
knownPerson(X) :- married(X,_,_).
knownPerson(X) :- married(_,X,_).
knownPerson(X) :- born(X,_,_).
```

To get rid of redundant answers of `knownPerson/1` we define an auxiliary predicate:

```
person(X) :- setof(t,knownPerson(X),_).
```

At last, let's see who's qualified, who not, and for which reasons. I took the data you supplied in the pastebin link:

```
?- person(P),
   setof(Q-Reason,person_qualified_reason(P,Q,Reason),Verdict).
P = aisling, Verdict = [yes-'has an Irish grandparent']           ;
P = andy,    Verdict = [no-'already a naturalized Irish citizen'] ;
P = anna,    Verdict = [yes-'has an Irish grandparent']           ;
P = brendan, Verdict = [no-'already an irish born citizen']       ;
P = bridgen, Verdict = [no-'already an irish born citizen']       ;
P = bridget, Verdict = [yes-'has an Irish parent'] ...
```